# Twilio outgoing browser call getting disconnected on hold

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, disconnect

I'm using [Twilio Outgoing Browser Calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client/outgoing-calls) in my project. The twiml to make call is like this :

```
<Response>
    <Dial action="hold_twiml.php" callerId="xxxxxxxxxx">
          xxxxxxxxxx
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

**hold_twiml.php**

```
if ( $_REQUEST['DialCallStatus'] == 'completed' ) { ?>
<Response>
    <Hangup/>
</Response>
<?php
}
else {
?>
<Response>
    <Play>http://demo.twilio.com/docs/classic.mp3</Play>
    <Redirect>hold_twiml.php</Redirect>
</Response>
<?php
}
?>
```

I want to disconnect the call when the call ends from client/browser. For that I've added the `if ( $_REQUEST['DialCallStatus'] == 'completed' )` condition and now the call is getting ended from both sides. But now the Hold feature is not working properly. When I click the hold button the following code will be executed.

```
if ( $action == 'hold' ) {
 $url = "holding_twiml.php";
 $call = $client->calls->read(
        array("ParentCallSid" => $_POST['callSid'])
    )[0];
} else {  // unhold
 $call = $client->calls($_POST['callSid'])->fetch();
 $url = "redirecting_twiml.php";
}
$call->update(
    array(
        "url" => $url,
        "method" => "POST"
    )
);
```

**holding_twiml.php**

```
<Response>
    <Enqueue waitUrl="hold_music_twiml.xml">xx</Enqueue>
</Response>
```

**hold_music_twiml.xml**

```
<Response>
    <Play>http://demo.twilio.com/docs/classic.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

**redirecting_twiml.php**

```
<Response>
  <Dial action="hold_twiml.php">
    <Queue>xx</Queue>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Now on clicking Hold, the call on browser is getting ended and the call over client(phone) is put into hold.

Can anyone help me to fix the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you solve it? i have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are using an [`action` attribute on the `<Dial>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action). From the documentation:

> If you provide an 'action' URL, Twilio will continue the current call
>   after the dialed party has hung up, using the TwiML received in your
>   response to the 'action' URL request.

So, when the client hangs up, Twilio is continuing the call using the TwiML received from your `action` URL.

If you remove the `action` attribute or change the TwiML to `<Hangup/>` then your call will end when the client hangs up.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: @Philnash..I have added action attribute for 'hold' functionality. So I can't avoid the action attribute.

Comment: Ok, you could check the `DialCallStatus` in the request to your action to see if the call is complete and then Hangup otherwise do the thing you need the action for.

Comment: I tried by checking `if ( $_REQUEST['DialCallStatus'] == 'completed' )` in hold_twiml.php page. Now it is getting disconnected from browser side also when client ends the call. But now Hold feature is not working fine. The call in browser end is getting disconnected while holding.

Comment: Ok, how do you put people on hold then? It might be best to update your question with some more details about what is going on so that I can help to get you a solution for this.

Comment: Thanks! Off the top of my head, why is hanging up your browser call bad? You don't need to play hold music to an agent and they can bring someone back from hold by creating a new call and dialling into the Queue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148595/discussion-between-jenz-and-philnash).